# Find Note issue

Tags: sirishortcuts

I am creating a shortcut that runs as a share extension. I want to append a result to a note (Apple Notes).

If the note does not exist I want to create it. My strategy is to find a note based on the Name and Creation Date (today).

I have a Find Note step that never finds notes whenever executed in a share extension but works fine when executed as a stand-alone from the Shortcuts app.

What may I be doing wrong? It does  not seem to me that the Find Note function should work differently depending on how the Shortcut is started.